# ggplot: extend title beyond plot margin

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a plot with some long labels and a long title.  I'm using `coord_flip()`, so there is a lot of space outside of the plot margins due to the labels.  By default the title is constrained to the plot margin.

How can I get the title to extend beyond the plot margin (to the left) so that it can span the entire width?  Here is an example:

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = cut)) + 
  geom_bar() + 
  coord_flip() + 
  scale_x_discrete("Cut", 
                   labels = c("Fair" = "Fair and a very long extra thing",
                              "Good" = "Good  and a very long extra thing",
                              "Very Good" = "VG  and a very long extra thing", 
                              "Premium" = "P and a very long extra thing. A very long label, just because", 
                              "Ideal" = "I and a very long extra thing")) + 
  ggtitle("This is my very long title.  Long long title. Very long.  The Longest. We have the best long titles.")
```

[image: My plot with long labels/title]

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21878974/324364) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37174316/324364) would be helpful?

Comment: @joran Thanks, I'm not after wrapping the labels (in my actual plot their isn't any free vertical space).  I'm just wanting the title to span the entire width.

Comment: Maybe `theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.95))` then?

Comment: @joran Jesus.  I just spent 30 minutes messing with margins and googling to no avail.  Now I feel stupid.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Yeah, we've all been there.

Comment: alternatively, `grid.arrange(ggplot(), top = "Title goes here")` places it across the whole viewport, not just over the panel.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe try this:

```
+ theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.95))
```

to move the title over.

Comment: I'm running into a followup problem.  When I have a multiline title, the hjust acts differently on each line.  I can't seem to find a different setting for justification versus reference point.  (Try putting a \n in the ggtitle and using hjust = -.5)

Answer (score 3):

Adding

```
+ theme(plot.title.position = "plot")
```

also does the trick, and allows the plot to span the whole width of the plot, even if it is just a short title.
I thought I'd leave this here because it took me a while to remember this solution after trying to search for it for a long time, and finding this page multiple times in the process.