# how to make all the x-axis label inside of the plot's border?

Tags: r, ggplot2

The x-axis top labels are out of the border in my plot, how can fit all the words in there?

I have tried the following, but seems not working:

```
theme(axis.text.x.top = element_text(margin = margin(...))
theme(axis.title.x.top = element_text(margin = margin(...))
```

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: what about decreasing size of the font (e.g. "text = element_text(size=20)")

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example, are you describing the text or title of the x axis or the facet text?

Comment: Are these facets? Looks like that. If this is a case then there's a dup: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37174316/how-to-fit-long-text-into-ggplot2-facet-titles